# Creating dataframe from a list

Tags: python, pandas

With the following code, I want to create a dataframe from a list based on the example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-lists/):

```
print(errors)
print(bench)
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(errors, columns=bench)
```

But I see this output and error message:

```
[445.66480707933385, 397.46150722911557, 4.750257647796286, 5.04022691040573, 36.046166609550546, 22.410673411769746, 19.478636563228537, 5.641660136926093, 0.8625482771381613, 0.6162884751878503, 1.8124491289448255e-14]
bfs_ny
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(errors, columns=bench)
...
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'bfs_ny' was passed
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: what are the `errors` and `benches` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a slight mistake when inputting your column name, you need to put a square bracket

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([445.66480707933385, 397.46150722911557, 4.750257647796286, 5.04022691040573, 36.046166609550546, 22.410673411769746, 19.478636563228537, 5.641660136926093, 0.8625482771381613, 0.6162884751878503, 1.8124491289448255e-14],columns=['bfs_ny'])

df_tmp
Out[88]: 
          bfs_ny
0   4.456648e+02
1   3.974615e+02
2   4.750258e+00
3   5.040227e+00
4   3.604617e+01
5   2.241067e+01
6   1.947864e+01
7   5.641660e+00
8   8.625483e-01
9   6.162885e-01
10  1.812449e-14
```

If it is variable, it's the same way:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(errors, columns=[bench])
```